# Acessing a table with keyboard buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

[image]

I have this table,is any way I can access that table with keyboard buttons?
Example if I press "W"I will be in [2,1] ,if I press button from keyboard "E" to be on [3,1].My table code similar to this image you see

```
function draw_empty_board() {
  var t = '<table id="chess_table">';
  for (var i = 2; i > 0; i--) {

    t += '<tr>';
    t += '<td class="line_label">' + i + '</td>';
    for (var j = 1; j < 13; j++) {


      t += '<td class="chess_square" id="square_' + j + '_' + i + '"></td>';

    }
    t += '</tr>';
  }
  t += '<tr><td class="column_label line_label"></td>';
  for (var j = 1; j < 13; j++) {

    t += '<td class="column_label">' + j + '</td>';
  }
  t += '</tr>';
  t += '</table>';

  $('#chess_board').html(t);
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate more . How (2,1) if w is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Here example: https://jsfiddle.net/3b2xcsoq/6/

```
function selectText(containerid) {
    if (document.selection) { // IE
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }
}

let activeRow = 1;
let activeColumn = 1;
let rowCount = 2;
let columnCount = 13;

function draw_empty_board() {
    var t = '<table id="chess_table">';
    for (var i = rowCount; i > 0; i--) {

        t += '<tr>';
        t += '<td class="line_label">' + i + '</td>';
        for (var j = 1; j < columnCount; j++) {


            t += '<td class="chess_square" id="square_' + j + '_' + i + '">' + j + ',' + i + '</td>';

        }
        t += '</tr>';
    }
    t += '<tr><td class="column_label line_label"></td>';
    for (var j = 1; j < 13; j++) {

        t += '<td class="column_label">' + j + '</td>';
    }
    t += '</tr>';
    t += '</table>';


    document.body.innerHTML = t;
}

function keyboardControl() {
    document.body.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
        switch (e.key) {
            case 'w':
            case 'W':
                if (activeRow < rowCount) {
                    activeRow++;
                }
                break;
            case 's':
            case 'S':
                if (activeRow > 1) {
                    activeRow--;
                }
                break;
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
                if (activeColumn < columnCount - 1) {
                    activeColumn++;
                }
                break;
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                if (activeColumn > 1) {
                    activeColumn--;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        selectText(`square_${activeColumn}_${activeRow}`);
    })
}

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    draw_empty_board();
    selectText(`square_${activeColumn}_${activeRow}`);
    keyboardControl();
});
```